# Use different connection strings at Home and Office

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2022

I need to connect to a different database location while working at Home than the one used at office.

How can I change connection strings in my asp.net mvc5 code?

Do you think that using Conditional Compilation Symbols would be ok?

I thought to add all my connection strings in the web.config file (HomeConnStr, OfficeConStr).
I would create a HOME compilation symbol, so I could use #if...#else to use one connection or the other one.

What do you think?

Is there a better, more "professional" option?

Thanks.